# Javascript assign doubleclick to all Selects

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to assign `onDblclick="this.form.submit();"` to all Selects in a form with jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: `$('select').on('dblclick',function(){});`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('select').on('dblclick',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```